# Node below and left of another node in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, context

I am using TikZ to make flowchart kind of diagrams. I want to get a node below and to the left of another node. Please see the following example. I want the replicate the sort of relationship between nodes `revealed` and `WTP measurement`. I have done that by creating an empty node directly below `WTP measurement` and then creating node `revealed` to the left of it. Is there an easier way? As you see in the code, I tried

```
   \node [level3, below left=of revealed, node distance=2in] (marketdata) {Market Data};
```

but that does not work. The node `marketdata` is not placed below and to the left of node `revealed`. In fact, it appears above it.

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[shapes,arrows]

\starttext

% Define block styles
\tikzstyle{level1} = [rectangle, draw, fill=green!40!blue!20, 
    text width=4in, text centered, inner sep=1pt, 
    minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{level2} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
    text width=2in, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\tikzstyle{level3} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!10, 
    text width=2in, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]

\starttikzpicture   
   % Place nodes
    \node [level1] (start) {\color[white]{WTP measurement}};
    \node [below of = start, node distance=1in] (blank) { };
    \node [level2, right of = blank, node distance=2in] (stated) {Stated Preference};
    \node [level2, left of = blank, node distance=2in] (revealed) {Revealed Preference};
    \node [level3, below left=of revealed, node distance=2in] (marketdata) {Market Data};


    % Draw edges
    \path [line] (start) -- (stated);
    \path [line] (start) -- (revealed);    
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. We prefer not to have any opening or closing text. As long the issue or solution is not ConTeXt specific the question should not be tagged with {context}.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

You need the `positioning` library loaded to use the relative positioning commands. And once you load it, `below left=of` should work fine.

```
\documentclass[border=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node [below left=of a] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: below left works]

Comment: You can change the distance by added a length just before `of`, like `below left=1cm of`. However, I never figured out how to change both directions independently, e.g. 2cm below but only 1cm to the left.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Just do `below left=2cm and 1cm of...`.

Comment: @MartinHeller: Thanks! See also Brent Longborough's answer.

Comment: @MartinHeller do you happen to know a keyword to place it exactly the same position?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is the `at` keyword and anchor specifications: `\node (a) at (0,0) {A};` `\node[anchor=center] (b) at (a.center) {B};`

Comment: The new formating requires it to start as `below left of=...`

Answer (score 71):

Building on @Seamus' answer and @Martin Scharrer's comment, try this:

```
\documentclass[border=1in]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (a) {A};
  \node [below left=1cm and 3cm of a] {B}; % Note the way the distances are specified
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Interestingly, `below left` works but `left below` doesn't...

Comment: @Seamus: Sacramental mysteries of the TikZ priesthood (;-»)

Comment: @Seamus: It a matter of definition. Also this would lead to an expression like "right above" instead of "above right", which might be confusing :-) ("A is right above B")

Comment: Thanks. I remember seeing this somewhere before but it didn't work for me somehow. Can't remember the details, but take your word for it.